# Pass configuration into a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to find a way to pass a configuration for a Multibranch pipeline job into the jenkinsfile when it's executing.

My goal is to configure something like the following:

```
Branch : Server
"master" : "prodServer"
"develop" : "devServer"
"release/*", "hotfix/*" : "stagingServer"
"feature/Thing-I-Want-To-Change-Regularly" : "testingServer"
```

where I can then write a Jenkinsfile like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        stage('Example Deploy') {
            when {
                //branch is in config branches
            }
            steps {
                //deploy to server
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to achieve this. [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) seems to be the solution for non-Pipeline projects, but it's currently got security issues and only partial Pipeline support.

Comment: I could hard code it into my Jenkinsfile, but then different branches might have different behaviour until changes merge through. ie, we want `feature/feature1` to deploy to testing, up until we want `feature/feature2` to deploy instead. But `feature1` doesn't get the memo depending how the the branches fall.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy to different servers depending on the branch, in Multibranch Pipelines you can use:

`when { branch 'master' }` (decalrative)

or

`${env.BRANCH_NAME}` (scripted)

to access which branch you are on and then add logic to deploy to corresponding servers based on this.

Comment: Yes, that's the "hard code it into jenkins" option I mentioned. The issue is when I say `branch 'feature/featureA'` then want to instead set `feature/featureB` to be the one deploying to a server, that only affects the jenkinsfile changes in `featureB`, and a new commit on `featureA` will still auto-deploy because it's jenkinsfile says so. Or I fix the jenkinsfile in `develop` and merge it into all other branches to try and keep them synced which is more work. I'm trying to have a single, global setting.

Answer (score 0):

Going to post my current best approach to a global config value and hope something better comes along.

---

In **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **Global Properties** you can define global Environment Variables which can be accessed from Jenkins jobs. Defining an *MY_BRANCH* variable there could be accessed from a pipeline.

```
when { branch: MY_BRANCH }
```

Or even a RegEx and used like this

```
when { expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ MY_BRANCH } }
```

However, this has the disadvantage that the Environment Variables are shared between every Jenkins job, not just across all branches of a single job. So careful naming will be necessary.